# Received ValueError: I/O operation on closed file but the data printed well

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sys

The data printed well according to the looping I make but I received File I/O error after it finish written on txt. I didnt indent all_true because it calculate total value. Can anybody tell whats wrong and why the system throws value i/o error?

Error: File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 277, in dispatch_shell sys.stdout.flush()

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

```
import sys

with open('testing.txt', 'w') as f:
  sys.stdout = f
  for i in range(len(train_idx)):
    training_data, testing_data = dataset.iloc[train_idx[i]], dataset.iloc[test_idx[i]]
    tree = CART(training_data, training_data, training_data.columns[:-1])

    y_pred = test(testing_data, tree)
    y_true = testing_data["class"]

    y_pred = np.array(y_pred).astype(str)
    y_true = np.array(y_true).astype(str)

    all_true.append(list(y_true))
    all_pred.append(list(y_pred))

    print("----------------- Fold {} --------------".format(i+1))

    # calculate precision, recall and f1-score
    calculate_metrics(y_true, y_pred)

    # plot confusion matrix
    plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)

  all_true = [v for item in all_true for v in item]
  all_pred = [v for item in all_pred for v in item]

  calculate_metrics(all_true, all_pred)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are indirectly closing a reference that points to stdout.  with automatically closes the file object f which you then set to sys.stdout and thus it gets closed try doing this instead:

```
with open('testing.txt', 'w') as f:
  stdout = sys.stdout
  sys.stdout = f
  ...
  ...
  # before the with statement ends.
  sys.stdout = stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file in write binaries mode.

```
with open('testing.txt', 'wb') as f:
...
```

Comment: still receive same error and with binaries the data not even written

Comment: Try closing the file when you end writting it using: testing.txt.close()